# cUrl alternatives to get POST answer on a webpage

Tags: php, javascript, html, curl

I would like to get the resulting web page of a specific form submit. This form is using POST so my current goal is to be able to send POST data to an url, and to get the HTML content of the result in a variable.

My problem is that i cannot use cUrl (not enabled), that's why i ask for your knowledge to know if an other solution is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'll try to find my way with it, even if it will be totally new for me ^^ Thanks

Answer (score 4):

See this, using fsockopen:
http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/post-request.htm

Fsockopen is in php standard library, so all php fron version 4 has it :)

Comment: My host (free.fr) apparently disabled also fsockopen and fopen on url 3 years ago. i'll look at your link anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try file_get_contents() and stream

```
$opts = array(  'http'=>array('method'=>"POST", 'content' => http_build_query(array('status' => $message)),));

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
```